# Matlab: Simple loop to store data to later be averaged and plotted

Tags: matlab

I am really rusty in matlab. I'm trying to make a few simple loops to store data to be averaged later.  For simplicity, let's say I have a cvs file with this data:
 
day, sec, chair, table 
1, 1.4, 38, 54 
2, 0, 45, 72 
 
3, 1, 37, 60
 
1, 0, 45, 72

I want to pull out every occurrence of day 1 into a bin, including the rest of the row, and then later average out the chair, table and sec for all day 1s.

Here is the code I currently have after I open the csv file, but it's not reading my 'if' loop.

```
day= data(:,1);
sec= data(:,2);
chair= data(:,3);
table= data(:,4);

for m = 1:length(data);
    if day==1;
        sec1(:,1)=sec(:,1);
        chair1(:,1)= chair(:,1);
        table1(:,1)= data(:,1);
    end
end
```

Also, I know I need to collect the data within the loop, but again have forgotten how, and the examples I have tried to look up haven't helped. Any ideas?

Comment: You're testing `day`, which is an array, against a constant `1`. Probably want something like `if day(m)==1`... Also `length(data)` returns the size of the maximum dimension. A more robust approach would be to use `size(data,1)` instead.

Comment: Ah - using day(m)==1 is MUCH better. THANK YOU! And, thank you for your advice regarding size vs length. I plugged it in and it is now running through the second loop. Now I am trying to get the code to bin sec1, chair1 and table1 correct. Currently,  it is saving all occurrences of each variable and not just the when  day = 1.

Comment: I added an answer which does it two different ways.

Comment: @jodag - this worked perfectly. Thank you!! I accepted the first answer without seeing the second. I am going to play with both. Regardless - they both answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example code fixes what I believe are your mistakes.

```
data = [1 1.4 38 54; ...
        2 0   45 72; ...
        3 1   37 60; ...
        1 0   45 72];

day= data(:,1);
sec= data(:,2);
chair= data(:,3);
table= data(:,4);

sec1 = [];
chair1 = [];
table1 = [];

for m = 1:size(data,1);
    if day(m)==1;
        sec1(end+1,1)=sec(m,1);
        chair1(end+1,1)= chair(m,1);
        table1(end+1,1)= data(m,1);
    end
end
```

The following gives the same results in a more condensed form

```
data = [1 1.4 38 54; ...
        2 0   45 72; ...
        3 1   37 60; ...
        1 0   45 72];

day= data(:,1);
sec= data(:,2);
chair= data(:,3);
table= data(:,4);

sec1 = sec(day==1,1);
chair1 = chair(day==1,1);
table1 = table(day==1,1);
```